# TextField hover highlight animation QML QtQuick.Control 2.15

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a textfield and I am trying to highlights its background when hovered. I am using a `PropertyAnimation` and it does not really do the animation:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

TextField {
    id: txtfield

    height: 40
    width: 250

    QtObject{
        id: internal

//        property var dynamicWidth: {if(txtfield.hovered){
//                                   console.log('Damn')
//                                   bg.border.width = 1.5
//                               }else{
//                                   bg.border.width = 0
//                               }
//        }
    }
    color: '#ffffff'
    placeholderTextColor: "#7fffffff"
    selectedTextColor: '#000000'
    selectionColor: '#ffffff'
    font.family: "Verdana"
    font.pointSize: 10
    placeholderText: qsTr('Enter full name...')
    hoverEnabled: true

    background: Rectangle{
        id: bg
        color: "#2c313c"
        border.color: "#aa0000"
//        border.width: internal.dynamicWidth
        radius: 10

        PropertyAnimation{
            id: widthAnimation
            target: bg // rectangle
            property: 'border.width'
            to: if(txtfield.hovered){
                    return 10
                }else{
                    return 0
                }
            duration: 500
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
        }    }
}
```

I am new and just learning JS, thanks in advance :D

Comment: This is not how you should start the animation. Replace the ``if-else`` with just ``10``  and use ``onHoveredChanged`` slot in your ``TextField`` to actually start the animation (``widthAnimation.start()``). You may also want to have two animations - when the mouse enters and leaves. This will be easier to do using states and transitions: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial3.html

Comment: Just realized TextField doesn't have ``onHoveredChanged`` slot. You colud still use MouseArea instead.

Comment: @splaytreez Could you provide an example on what you mean?

Comment: @CoolClound I'll post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation won't start when the `txtfiled.hovered` property changes as you expect. To start the animation you should use the `start()` method. Solution 1:

```
    TextField {
        id: txtfield

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        height: 40
        width: 250

        QtObject{

        }
        color: '#ffffff'
        placeholderTextColor: "#7fffffff"
        selectedTextColor: '#000000'
        selectionColor: '#ffffff'
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pointSize: 10
        placeholderText: qsTr('Enter full name...')

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onHoveredChanged: {
                if (containsMouse) {
                    widthAnimation.start();
                } else {
                    bg.border.width = 0;
                }
            }
            onClicked: {
                txtfield.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }

        background: Rectangle{
            id: bg
            color: "#2c313c"
            border.color: "#aa0000"
            //        border.width: internal.dynamicWidth
            radius: 10

            PropertyAnimation{
                id: widthAnimation
                target: bg // rectangle
                property: 'border.width'
                to: 10
                duration: 500
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, you may want to have an animation when the mouse leaves the TextArea. This is better to do using states and transitions:

```
    TextField {
        id: txtfield

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        height: 40
        width: 250

        QtObject{
            id: internal
        }
        color: '#ffffff'
        placeholderTextColor: "#7fffffff"
        selectedTextColor: '#000000'
        selectionColor: '#ffffff'
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pointSize: 10
        placeholderText: qsTr('Enter full name...')

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onHoveredChanged: {
                if (containsMouse) {
                    bg.state = "hovered"
                } else {
                    bg.state = "unhovered"
                }
            }
            onClicked: {
                txtfield.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }

        background: Rectangle{
            id: bg
            color: "#2c313c"
            border.color: "#aa0000"
            radius: 10

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "hovered"
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: bg
                        border.width: 10
                    }
                },
                State {
                    name: "unhovered"
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: bg
                        border.width: 0
                    }
                }
            ]
            transitions: [
                Transition {
                    from: "*"
                    to: "*"
                    PropertyAnimation {
                        property: "border.width"
                        duration: 300
                        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

More about states and transitions: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial3.html

Comment: Nice, this does work. Can you tell me what, `from: "*"` means?

Comment: @CoolCloud Usually, you have several transitions between different states. ``from`` and ``to`` properties specify to which state changes (from which state and to which state) the transition must apply. Here, the animation for showing the border is the same as the animation for hiding the border, so it's enough to have only one transition that applies to *any* state change -- this is what the ``*``  is for. This was a very poor explanation so you should read the documentation; it'll become much more clear

Comment: That is fine, I get it. Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: I did notice, in the solution 2. The border is already highlighted when the code is executed. Any idea why?

Comment: @CoolCloud That's weird because I didn't have that problem when I ran it, but it's nothing serious: adding ``state: "unhovered"`` must fix it.

Comment: Where should I add that?

Comment: @CoolCloud to the background item